# MS Access : How do delete one record with multiple criteria?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to delete one record in a table.  I have two unbounds, one with a number and one with a date and then a command button to execute the code.  So in my table I assign these values and they go in the table in their seperate column and contain the "Name, Number, Date".  So say I want to delete this record, all I do is enter the number into one unbound and the date into the other unbound and then click the button and it should delete.  The problem I am getting is "Error 13(Type mismatch) in procedure..."  Here is my code below:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM CrewTable WHERE KitNumber = " & Me.txtClearKitEntry And ActionDate = " & Me.txtClearDateEntry"
CurrentDb.Execute dbFailOnError
Me.Crew.Requery
```

Again, the KitNumber is a number and ActionDate is a date.  I thought for dates you need to use '#' but I got errors with that.  So I feel I just have some quotes and that kind of stuff in the wrong order.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM CrewTable WHERE KitNumber = " & Me.txtClearKitEntry And ActionDate = " & Me.txtClearDateEntry"
```

To this

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM CrewTable WHERE KitNumber = " & Me.txtClearKitEntry & " And ActionDate = #" & Me.txtClearDateEntry & "#;"
```

part of you string was not in quotes and also when using dates in sql queries **in Access** they have to be wrapped in `#`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you clarify a little more? I feel like the end of that expression wouldn't make much sense with all those quotes. Wouldn't `ActionDate = #" & Me.txtClearDateEntry" & "#;"` need to have an ending a little cleaner?

Comment: If you were to look at this as a string after it has pulled from the txtboxes you would get `"DELETE FROM CrewTable WHERE KitNumber = 4 And ActionDate = #01/01/2013#;"`  That is just how Access is.

Comment: @Patrick Also if I answered your question please mark this answer as the best answer.  Thank you :D

Comment: I believe that. But when I copy that line of code in place of my old one, I can't even test it out becasue I get a "Compile error:Expects end of statement" and then highlights `" & "`

Comment: @Patrick It should be correct now.  I had a `&` in the wrong spot.  Copy and past it again into your code and it should compile.  I just ran the code and it works fine now with mu correction.